# does a <directory> directive need to be inside <virtualhost>?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a bunch of URLs which all point to the same directory on the server in apache's conf files. The basic structure is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/thesite

  <Directory /var/www/thesite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, each one is essentially identical, just changing the SeverName and ServerAlias directives.

Is it permissible to move the `<Directory>` directive to the top, outside of the `<VirtualHost>`? And, while I'm at is, is there any reason I can't list a dozen sites as `SeverAlias` even if they're completely different?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it permissible to move the  directive to the top,
>   outside of the `<VirtualHost>`

Yes, but it'd be more logical to leave it where it is.

> is there any reason I can't list a dozen sites as SeverAlias

```
ServerAlias www.mysite.com anotherdomain.com yetanotherdomain.com
```

is valid, but the site returned will be the one at /var/www/thesite.